# Create a custom landing page before the wordpress home page and then redirect to the wordpress home page

Tags: wordpress

I am wanting to create a landing page with html / css / js where when the user enters see the landing and after some time redirects to the page of wordpress. (All in the same domain)

- Try playing the .htaccess but the problem is that it takes me to the same place always:

## BEGIN WordPress RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project/index.php

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]

DirectoryIndex ./landing/test.html

## END WordPress

- This would be my landing page (it does a redirect with js) but it creates a loop always to the same landing

$(function () {

$(".logo").fadeIn(2000);

$(".tlt").fadeIn(1000);

$(".tlt2").fadeIn(1000);

$('.tlt').textillate();

$('.tlt2').textillate({

initialDelay: 1000

});

setTimeout(function(){

url = "./";

$(location).attr('href',url);

},5000);

})

Comment: I think, you're complicating this process. Create your landing page in wordpress, then set that page as homepage under settings, once the user enters your site, then use PHP or JS to redirect them after a given time. You don't necessarily need htaccess for this at all.

Comment: But this give the same layout of the wordpress theme.. the landing i want have another design and animation of text

Comment: Create a different template for both pages.

Comment: i created a template for the static page, and how can i use the default front-page.php for the redirection